numactl: Is it possible to use cpu and memory from different numa nodes?
The numactl man page says:

--membind=nodes, -m nodes Only allocate memory from nodes. Allocation will fail when there is not enough memory available on these nodes.
nodes may be specified as noted above.
--cpunodebind=nodes, -N nodes Only execute command on the CPUs of nodes. Note that nodes may consist of multiple CPUs. nodes may be
specified as noted above.

So these 2 options look independent of each other.
Suppose I have two NUMA nodes. Node 0 is equipped with CPUs and RAMs. Node 1 is a purely memory node.
Is it possible to use CPU from node 0 and memory from node 1? Like this:

numactl --cpunodebind=0  --membind=1  <executable>

I expect the result of the above command to be like this:

The binary of the executable is loaded into node 1's memory and cpu from node 0
will execute from that memory.

ADD 1
Some relevant findings from here:

The difference between --membind and --preferred is that --preferred
allows memory from other sockets to be allocated if the current socket
is out of memory. --membind does not allow memory to be allocated
outside the specified socket.

This quote implies there needs to be a socket/cpu in the node. But I am not sure if it is correct.

Well, I can't give you a definite answer but I've used mbind(…, MPOL_PREFERRED, …) with CPUs set to one NUMA node and specific memory (not all) set to another. It seemed to work.

@Homer512 Thanks for the comment. I have tried numa_alloc_onnode() (https://linux.die.net/man/3/numa_alloc_onnode. ) It looks similar to mbind(). But it has the same effect of numactl based on my experiment.
